# HTML POST Form doesn't send any data to PHP script

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a drop-down menu that gets populated by a PHP script that queries a MySQL database (very simple table, each row is just an id and a name).

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="query.php">

        <select>
            <option selected="yes">Choose value</option>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo '
                <option value="'.$row['id'].'" name="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>
                ';
                }
                ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This works and apparently renders fine:

[image]

Query.php is just a test script with a single line, just to see if the form is actually sending data.

```
<?php 
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

It doesn't. All I get when I submit the form is is array(0) { }. The form doesn't send anything to the script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `name` attribute.

Comment: Could it be thy typo Query.php vs query.php?

Comment: you don't have a select name=?? it needs to be <select name="select_box">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` is a **key-value** array. Where `key` is value of `name` attribute of html element (`input`, `select`, `textarea`). Without `name` - how will you get the value from `$_POST`? So, it is:

```
<select name="some_name">
```

And on server:

```
echo $_POST['some_name'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You gotta give your `select` a name like:

```
<select name="name">
```

Comment: Doh. I knew it was something extremely simple I had overlooked. Thanks.